# How to retreive or display the information after you scan the QR code?

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, qr-code

**MainActivity.class:**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null) {
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Result Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                try {
                    //converting the data to json
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());
                    Toast.makeText(this, obj.getString("id"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();available on the qrcode
                    Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

How can I get the data into a MySQL database, when a QR code is scanned?

Comment: did you insert data into database when response come from scan?

Comment: I have already database, also the information with qr image and I want to do is when I scan on it it should detect the qr image and it will appear the data info. @HemantParmar

Comment: Connect QR Code Scanner android app to online mySQL database

Comment: based on QR number you have fetch the data from data base

Comment: do you have information stored in database..then only u will be able to fetch this

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this,

```
IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null) {
            //if qrcode has nothing in it
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, " Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());
                 //   Toast.makeText(this,"results"+ result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  //  Toast.makeText(this,"results again : "+ result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    staffLoginQRCODE(result.getContents());
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }




private void staffLoginQRCODE(final String check_result) {
hit your api for resonse      }
```

Comment: Sir, how it will get the information on the database?

Comment: Connect QR Code Scanner android app to mySQL database

Comment: when qrcode read you have to pass database id to get info. result.getContents() is your databse id when you scan qrcode.

Comment: example sir, you have 2 tables. the other table have qr_id then the other is book_id, it based in the id, example qr_id = 1 and book_id = 1, when you scan the qr it will display the book_id `1`, all the data of book_id `1`

Comment: example sir, you have 2 tables. the other table have qr_id then the other is book_id, it based in the id, example qr_id = 1 and book_id = 1, when you scan the qr it will display the book_id 1, all the data of book_id 1